# open and modify mdb file from azure blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an mdb file in storage azure blob, i must read and modify that file without download it with some query in c# and i must show info in a web page(javascript, html).

```
[ViewItem(nameof(StorageRetriveDB), "Files", "GET - StorageRetriveDB")]
public List<string> StorageRetriveDB([FromUri] string id)
{
    List<string> ListboxItems = new List<string>();
    string url = "blobname";
    var storageAccount =
        CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureStorageConnectionString-1"]);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(url);
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("mydb.mdb");
    if (blob.Exists())
    {
        using (var stream = blob.OpenRead())
        {
            string connString = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=LINKTOMYAZUREBLOBSTORAGE/mydb.mdb";
            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                OdbcDataReader reader = null;
                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * from tbVariablesMap", connection);
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ListboxItems.Add(reader[0].ToString() + "," + reader[1].ToString() + "," +
                                     reader[2].ToString() + "," + reader[3].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ListboxItems;
}
```

`connection.Open();` causes a crash, with local db it works but in azure blob storage it doesn't work!

Comment: What error is shown when the Open call crashed the app? Are the credentials valid?

Comment: no credentials needed, i have no error! :(

Answer (score 0):

In your access database connection string , the "Dbq" parameter should be a file path to your mdb file.

However, Azure blob storage is not designed for this. As it is said in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction#blob-storage) :

> Blob storage is ideal for:
>
> ```
> Serving images or documents directly to a browser.
> Storing files for distributed access.
> Streaming video and audio.
> Storing data for backup and restore, disaster recovery, and archiving.
> Storing data for analysis by an on-premises or Azure-hosted service.
> ```
>
> Objects in Blob storage can be accessed from anywhere in the world via
>   HTTP or HTTPS. Users or client applications can access blobs via URLs,
>   the Azure Storage REST API, Azure PowerShell, Azure CLI, or an Azure
>   Storage client library.

If you were using Linux OS, then there might be a solution with blob storage. You can [mount Blob storage as a file system with blobfuse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux). After that, you can access blob as accessing your local file. But blobfuse doesn't guarantee 100% POSIX compliance.

---

An other optional way is to use Azure file share. You can mount a network driver, and then you can access files in it.

Comment: the Dbq parameter in my code is the file path to my mdb.

Comment: local file path?

Comment: local file path works,
azure blob storage file path doesn't work

Comment: That is correct. Just as I said in my answer, a file path is needed for Dbq. However,  Azure blob storage is not designed as a file system. You can not use it like that way.

Comment: I do not think it will work. A file path is needed.  Not a http url or a ftp url.  And, is there any FTP service in Azure? I did not find it.